# Showing $\langle a,p,q\mid p^{-1}ap=a^2, q^{-1}aq=a^2\rangle$ is non-hopfian (from first principles).

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory, hopfian

*According to a search on Approach0, this question is new to MSE.*

### Motivation for Study:

I'm doing some light reading of some notes by Miller on combinatorial group theory. Hopfian groups have just been defined. Whilst I've seen the term used countless times before now, I have not yet once played with it. So here goes . . .

### The Details:

The following is the definition I'm working with.

> **Definition:** A group $G$ is *hopfian* if whenever $G/N\cong G$, we have that $N$ is the trivial group.
>
> **Lemma:** Any group $G$ is hopfian iff every epimorphism $\alpha: G\to G$ is an automorphism.

The proof of this Lemma seems elementary to me, so, with a few qualms, I'll leave it out.

### The Question:

> **Question:** (G. Higman) Show that the group $H$ with presentation
> $$\langle a,p,q\mid p^{-1}ap=a^2, q^{-1}aq=a^2\rangle$$
> is non-hopfian.

**For extra credit to those that answer (but no promised bounty):**

> Complete the exercise *from first principles*, please; that is, without any fancy footwork, so as to make clear the concept of (not) being hopfian.

### My Attempt:

My goal is to exhibit an epimorphism $\psi: G\to G$ that is not an automorphism.

Define $\psi$ by

$$\begin{align}
p &\mapsto p,\\
q &\mapsto q,\\
a &\mapsto a^2.
\end{align}$$

Would this work? I'm not sure of whether it's an epimorphism, let alone not an automorphism.

I have $$\psi(p)\psi(q)=pq\stackrel{?}{=}\psi(pq)$$ (because $\psi$ is defined on the generators, right? So the same must be for the $qp$ case; the $\psi(a^2)=\psi(a)\psi(a)$ case is trivial).

Moreover, I have, since $a^2p=pa$ by the first relation, that $$\psi(a)\psi(p)=a^2p=pa\stackrel{?}{=}\psi(ap);$$ the $\psi(aq)$ bit is similar.

What I'm struggling with is $\psi(p)\psi(a)=pa^2$ and so on.

Please help :)

*Disclaimer:*

I'm in hospital at the moment and so I'm on a break from my PhD. (I've been here a month now.) The above is just for fun and has little if anything at all, *a priori*, to do with my research.

Comment: the first relation does *not* say that $a^2p = ap$, it says that $pa^2 = ap$.

Comment: Well spotted,  @RyleeLyman. Thank you. I have edited it now.

Comment: It's obviously surjective since $\{p,q,a^2\}$ generates the group (it suffices to check that $a$ belongs to the subgroup it generates).

Comment: The element $w=pap^{-1}(qaq^{-1})^{-1}$ clearly belongs to the kernel of your epimorphism. The whole point is to show that $w\neq 1$. I don't see an entirely elementary way to prove it. It can be proved from basic properties of amalgams, since your group is the amalgam of two solvable Baumslag-Solitar groups (namely $\langle p,a|p^{-1}ap=a^2\rangle$ and $\langle q,b|p^{-1}bp=b^2\rangle$ amalgamating $a=b$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checking that $\psi$ is a homomorphism is routine: $p^{-1}ap = a^2 \Rightarrow p^{-1}a^2p = a^4$, so $\psi(p^{-1}ap) = p^{-1}a^2p = a^4 = \psi(a^2)$, and similarly $\psi(q^{-1}aq) = \psi(a^2)$. So $\psi$ is a homorphism.

Since $a = pa^2p^{-1} \in {\rm Im}(\psi)$, $\psi$ is an epimorphism.

The tricky bit is to show that $\psi$ is not injective.

Note that  $\psi(pap^{-1}) = pa^2p^{-1} = a = qa^2q^{-1} = \psi(qaq^{-1
})$.

So if we could show that $pap^{-1} \ne qaq^{-1}$ (in $G$) then we would be done.

That follows from Britton's Lemma about HNN-extensions, but since they are asking you to prove it from first principles, I am guessing that ther emust be soem way of doing it directly without recourse to Britton's Lemma. Unfortunately I haven't figured out how to do that yet!

Comment: but $p^{-1}ap = q^{-1}aq = a^2$ by definition!

Comment: Yes, I interchanged $p$ and $p^{-1}$. I have fixed that now.

Comment: Well, Britton's Lemma is in the previous chapter o' notes. Thank you, @DerekHolt. The first principles thing is just my own, rather silly approach to rigour, I suppose.

Comment: For a word $w$ in G define $\sigma(w)$ as the sum of the absolute value of the exponents with which $a$ occurs in that word. The two relators then satisfy $\sigma(r) = 3$ . For $w = pap^{-1}qa^{-1}q^{-1}$ we have $\sigma(w) = 2$ so $w$ cannot be expressed  as a composition of relators.

Comment: @MarcBogaerts $w=p^{-1}apq^{-1}a^{-1}q$ has $\sigma(w)=2$ but represents the trivial element

Comment: So let's refine the definition of $\sigma$ by stating that $\sigma(w)$ = $\sigma(\overline{w})$   where $\overline{w}$ is the expression of $w$ that cannot be simplified  further.

Comment: @MarcBogaerts so everything which represents the trivial element(production relators and conjugates) has $\sigma(w)=0$? Then how do you know that the $w$ for the problem is reduced and can't be reduced anymore? Also not being able to simplify further isn't exactly well defined (I know what that means in free groups but other groups it isn't always clear).

Comment: I went a bit on Google and I found this: https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXoypizjW3WknFiJnKLwHCnL72vedxjQkDDP1mXWo6uco/wiki/Word_(group_theory).html#mw0w what affirms your statement

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in my comment and in Derek's answer, the whole point is to prove that $w=pap^{-1}(qaq^{-1})^{-1}\neq 1$.

First a remark: since this element belongs to the kernel of a surjective endomorphism, it belongs to all finite index subgroups, and in particular to the derived (and even the second derived) subgroup. This is typically a reason for an element to discard too obvious proofs of its non-triviality.

1) The arguments given in my comment (using an amalgam decomposition) and in Derek's (using an HNN-decomposition) are quite similar (these point of views were essentially unified in Bass-Serre theory.

2) Let me provide another proof using the group $G$ of oriented self-homeomorphisms of $\mathbf{R}$; it is easier if this combinatorial stuff is not taken for granted. To show the non-triviality of $w$, it is enough to find three elements $p,q,a$ of $G$ satisfying the two relators, and such that $w(p,q,a)\in G$ is $\neq 1$.

Namely, write $a(x)=x+1$ and $p(x)=x/2$, so $p^{-1}\circ a\circ p=a\circ a$ while $p\circ a\circ p^{-1}(x)=x+\frac12$. Define $s(x)=x+\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{2\pi}$. Then $s\in G$, $s$ commutes with $a$ but not with $c=p\circ a\circ p^{-1}$. Define $q=s\circ p\circ s^{-1}$. Then $q^{-1}\circ a\circ q=a\circ a$; moreover $p\circ a\circ p^{-1}\neq q\circ a\circ q^{-1}$ (since equality would mean that $s$ commutes with $c$).

Comment: I am not really sure what the last part is going for as $s$ is not a homeomorphism and $s,a$ do not commute.

Comment: @PaulPlummer thanks, I fixed the typo (I meant "$x+$", but all my concentration went to correctly type the fraction...!)